# Shiny with dygraphs package

Tags: shiny, dygraphs

I am trying to use shiny with dygraphs. I try to produce a graph that would show time series data depending on the input variables. The sample of the data is the following:

```
     date      product sold
1  2015-01-01       a    1
2  2015-01-01       b   20
3  2015-02-01       a    2
4  2015-02-01       b   15
5  2015-03-01       a    3
6  2015-03-01       b   10
7  2015-04-01       a    4
8  2015-04-01       b    5
9  2015-05-01       a    5
10 2015-05-01       b    1
```

What I want is a time series graph with checkbox controls for the product variable (to see  product a, b or both).

The ui and server code are (shinydashboard package):

```
library(shiny)
library(dygraphs)
library(dplyr)
library(xts)


ui <- dashboardPage(
skin="black",
dashboardHeader(title = "title"),
dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Results", tabName = "Result1", icon = icon("th"))
  )),
dashboardBody(
  tabItems(

    tabItem(tabName = "Result1",
            fluidRow(
              dygraphOutput("Graph")
            ),

            sidebarPanel(
              uiOutput("output1")
            )

    )

  ) )
 )

 server <- function(input, output) {


 output$Graph <- renderDygraph({

  data_f <- filter(data_products,
               product==input$type)
  xts(data_f$sold, as.Date(data_f$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")) %>%
    dygraph()
  })
  output$output1<-renderUI({
  selectizeInput("type","Choose product",
   choices=levels(data_products$product), multiple=TRUE)
  })
   }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

tried several approaches but always get errors. Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Show us what you think it is your best approach and what error you get with it please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be careful in this part of the code:

```
data_f <- filter(data_products,
               product==input$type)
```

In this example, depending on your choices `input$type` can contain 0, 1 or 2 elements. If it contains one element `"a"` or `"b"` then everything is fine, however in other cases your going to get errors or warnings.

If you haven't selected any value in your widget, `input$type` is going to return `NULL`. Hence, logical comparison is going to fail and you are going to get errors. To avoid this it - before using the missing input - you can use `req` or `validate` functions which can be read as "require that an input is available" . [Here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/req.html) you can read more about handling missing inputs in shiny.

If you selected both `"a"` and `"b"` `product==input$type` is going to return a warning because `==` doesn't work for multiple comparisions. Instead of this just change it to `%in%`.

Since you want a checkbox I changed `selectInput` to  `checkboxGroupInput`

---

**Full example:**

```
library(shiny)
library(dygraphs)
library(dplyr)
library(xts)

# I pasted your example data to exces and then readed it into R with these 
# two lines of the code. It seems that product has to be a factor, because you
# use 'levels(data_products$product)'
# data_products <- as.data.frame(read_excel("~/Downloads/data.xlsx"))[-1]
# data_products$product <- as.factor(data_products$product)


ui <- dashboardPage(
  skin="black",
  dashboardHeader(title = "title"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Results", tabName = "Result1", icon = icon("th"))
    )),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(

      tabItem(tabName = "Result1",
              fluidRow(
                dygraphOutput("Graph")
              ),

              sidebarPanel(
                uiOutput("output1")
              )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$Graph <- renderDygraph({
    req(input$type) # require that input$type is available

    data_f <- filter(data_products,
                     product %in% input$type) # use "%in%" instead of "=="  
    xts(data_f$sold, as.Date(data_f$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")) %>%
      dygraph()
  })
  output$output1 <- renderUI({
    # selectizeInput("type","Choose product",
    #                choices=levels(data_products$product), multiple=TRUE)
    checkboxGroupInput("type", "Choose product",
                       choices = levels(data_products$product),
                       selected = levels(data_products$product))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

**EDITED**:

If you want to have two lines when `a` and `b` are selected, you have to change the format of your data - you have to go from long to wide. The reason for that is that you can then easily create a bivariate time series with `xts` and `dygraph` will plot two separate lines.

Going from long to wide is easily accomplished with the `reshape2` package from Hadley Wickham.

```
# Copy data from your example
data_products <- read.table(con<-file("clipboard"),header=T)
data_products$product <- as.factor(data_products$product)
# Reshape 
data_products <- dcast(data_products, date ~ product)
```

Your dataset looks now like this:

```
        date a  b
1 2015-01-01 1 20
2 2015-02-01 2 15
3 2015-03-01 3 10
4 2015-04-01 4  5
5 2015-05-01 5  1
```

Due to the new nature of the data, you have to slightly change the code on the server side. I left the comments in the code

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  skin = "black",
  dashboardHeader(title = "title"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Results", tabName = "Result1", icon = icon("th"))
    )),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(

      tabItem(tabName = "Result1",
              fluidRow(
                dygraphOutput("Graph")
              ),

              sidebarPanel(
                uiOutput("output1")
              )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$Graph <- renderDygraph({
    req(input$type) # require that input$type is available

    # Due to the wide format we have to select columns
    data_f <- data_products[, c("date", input$type)]
    # univariate or bivariate time series
    xts(data_f[-1], as.Date(data_f$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")) %>%
      dygraph()
  })

  output$output1 <- renderUI({
    # Since we now have data in wide format, the choices are 
    # the names of columns (expect date)
    checkboxGroupInput("type", "Choose product", 
                       choices = names(data_products)[-1])
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! Just one more thing. If I select now both "a" and "b" in the checkbox, only one line appears and not two... I know these are beginner questions, but I am new to R and Shiny. Thanks.

Comment: I updated my post above. It turned out that the solution is quite easy because it only requires changing the format of the data

Comment: This is great! The best answer I have found - surprisingly, there is not much (on specifically this issue of multiple selections) on shiny + dygraphs. Thanks!